# $L(H)$ and functions belong to predual of this space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Does every W*-continuous linear functional belong to $L^1(H)$? is it true? I cannot understand about it. Please regard me.

Answer (score 1):

By Sakai's theorem every von Nuemann algebra $M$ have as Banach space the unique predual $M_*$ which is the set of weak-$^*$ continuous functionals on $M$.

On the other hand the algebra $L(H)$ of bounded operators is trivially a von Neumann algebra and it is known that its predual is the set of trace class operators $L_1(H)$